# Convert Int16 to String Swift 4

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert an Int16 value to String but it gives value with Optional, won't allow me to forced unwrap it.

```
String(describing:intValue)
```

**Result :** Optional(intValue)

Comment: Never use `String(describing:)` to convert any value to a string that will be shown to the user.

Comment: "won't allow me to forced unwrap it." -> That ***really*** should not be your first instinct.

Answer (score 4):

Unwrap `intValue` first, then pass it to the string initializer: `String(unwrappedIntValue)`

Here are some ways of handling the optional. I've added explicit `string#` variables with type annotations, to make it clear what types are involved

```
let optionalInt: Int? = 1

// Example 1
// some case: print the value within `optionalInt` as a String
// nil case:  "optionalInt was nil"

if let int = optionalInt {
    let string1: String = String(int)
    print(string1)
}
else {
    print("optionalInt was nil")
}

// Example 2, use the nil-coalescing operator (??) to provide a default value
// some case: print the value within `optionalInt` as a String
// nil case:  print the default value, 123

let string2: String = String(optionalInt ?? 123)
print(string2)

// Example 3, use Optional.map to convert optionalInt to a String only when there is a value
// some case: print the value within `optionalInt` as a String
// nil case:  print `nil`

let string3: String? = optionalInt.map(String.init)
print(string3 as Any)

// Optionally, combine it with the nil-coalescing operator (??) to provide a default string value
// for when the map function encounters nil:
// some case: print the value within `optionalInt` as a String
// nil case:  print the default string value "optionalInt was nil"

let string4: String = optionalInt.map(String.init) ?? "optionalInt was nil"
print(string4)
```

Comment: It gives error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'Int16'"

Comment: @SantoshSingh that doesn't make sense though, what value is optional?

Comment: In that case, I don't think your Int16 is optional.  Have you tried using `String(intValue)` (without the `describing:`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a number to a `String` with string interpolation:

```
let stringValue = "\(intValue)"
```

Or you can use a standard `String` initializer:

```
let stringValue = String(intValue)
```

If the number is an `Optional`, just unwrap it first:

```
let optionalNumber: Int? = 15

if let unwrappedNumber = optionalNumber {
  let stringValue = "\(unwrappedNumber)"
}
```

Or

```
if let unwrappedNumber = optionalNumber {
  let stringValue = String(unwrappedNumber)
}
```

Comment: If `intValue` is an optional, this will have the same issue as `String(describing:)`.

Comment: @Alexander You are right - I just added to my answer.

Comment: I would also suggest against using string interpolation for just a single varirable. It's more cluttered than just `String(int)`

Comment: @Alexander To each his/her own.  I added both options in my answer.

Comment: why don't you use the same name spacing when unwrapping it? `if let intValue = intValue {`

Comment: @creeperspeak For one, `String(int)` plays nicely with StackOverflow's syntax highlighting, as well as the relatively primitive Swift syntax highlighting of text editors other than Xcode

Comment: @LeoDabus I tend to use different names when writing answers in SO simply because new Swift users often have a hard time understanding how optional binding works.  I feel using different names makes it easier to infer what is going on.  If you feel that makes the answer more confusing let me know.

Comment: You can just add a comment saying that it is not optional (unwrapped)  inside the brackets

Comment: @creeperspeak I would prefer your approach, but with more useful names... i.e. `if let unwrappedValue = optionalValue ...`. Then introduce the idea "well `unwrappedValue` was a rather arbitrary name, we can just shadow `optionalValue` instead."

Comment: @Alexander Good call.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you want to have different names just add optional in front `optionalValue` and remove it when unwrapping it `value`. But I am against adding type information to the variable name. If you option click it you can see its type

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree, I'm not a fan of "Hungarian notation" in the general case, either. But I think stack overflow answers should be clear on their own, without the need to try the code out in Xcode just for a few type annotations